# How do I force my text to be right justified in JTextFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jtextfield

I'm trying to make my text fields to be right aligned, but I'm not quite sure how to make them right aligned in the JTextField. I read that you can make the Jtextfield right jusitified, but I just can't find the correct syntax.

### currently, they're left justified.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class RecursivePowerCalculator extends JFrame {
//text fields for base, exponent, and power. 
private JTextField jtfBase = new JTextField();
private JTextField jtfExponent = new JTextField();
private JTextField jtfPower = new JTextField();

//button to press called calcuate
private JButton jbtCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");

//constructor
public RecursivePowerCalculator(){
    jtfPower.setEditable(false);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));

    p1.add(new JLabel("Base"));
    p1.add(jtfBase);

    p1.add(new JLabel("Exponent"));
    p1.add(jtfExponent);

    p1.add(new JLabel("Power"));
    p1.add(jtfPower);

    JPanel p2 =new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    p2.add(jbtCalculate);

    //add the panels to the frame
    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jbtCalculate.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
 }

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //get values from text fields
        double base = Double.parseDouble(jtfBase.getText());
        double exponent = Double.parseDouble(jtfExponent.getText());

       String pNum = "" + (power(base, exponent));
        jtfPower.setText(pNum);
 }
    private double power(double x, double y){
     if ( y == 0)
         return 1.0;
     else
        return power(x,y - 1) * x;
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `jtfPower.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);`
See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29).